# Is drag-and-drop possible in chrome-webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit4, selenium-chromedriver

I cannot get drag-and drop working with the Java Junit WebDriver bindings. I am working with Google Chrome on Windows.I have used below code,but i did not work.

```
{WebElement draggable = driver.findElement(By.id("source")); 
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.id("target")); 
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.dragAndDrop(element, to).build().perform();
    builder.clickAndHold(element).moveToElement(to).release(to).build().perform();}
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. What exactly didn't work? Did in work in Firefox, for example?

Comment: my application does not run in Firefox or IE.it is a dual tree Drag and Drop functionality i have to automate.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following solution (it works for us):

```
WebElement dragArea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#" + idDragProduct"));
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#" + idTarget));
new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(dragArea).moveToElement(to).release().build().perform();
```

In case you want to try and test drag-and-drop as functionality, it's not neccesary to move it to another element.
You can do:

```
WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#" + idTarget));
new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(dragArea).moveByOffset(X_OFF,Y_OFF).release().build().perform();
```